# React native: invoke method dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to invoke dynamically named method in Javascript.

I'm using `React Native` and when assign `ref` in `TextInput` I need that set dynamically method.

```
renderInput(id) {
    <TextInput
        ref={(input) => this.myInput = input}
    />
}
```

I need dynamic `this.myInput`.

I've tested it and got it wrong: `this.myInput[id]` and `this[id].myInput`

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. What is "dynamic this.myinput"?

Comment: You should read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) Mahdi...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.inputs = {};
}


//  params Object should be in this format   {id:324, referenceKey: 'one'};

renderTextInput(params) {
  return <TextInput ref={input => { this.inputs[params.referenceKey] = input }}/>
}
```

// Using the refernce

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.inputs['one'].focus()
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I did it and got it wrong. ` Cannot set property 'one' of undefined`

Comment: you need to  define a state with name input.

Comment: constructor() {  this.input: {};}

Comment: I did this, but I did not get any results

Comment: no need to define as state variable. Simply define as this.inputs  = {} is enough

Comment: my pleasure :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [current](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs):

```
this.myInput.current[id]
```

---

Here's how:

```
// First, create a reference (in the constructor)
this.myInput = React.createRef()
// Then, assign the ref (in the element)
 <TextInput ref={this.myInput} />
// Now, to access the reference
// this.myInput.current.<<property you wanted to access>>
this.myInput.current[id] // id is defined as a variable
// this will get the dom id
// this.myInput.current.id
```

---

But if you insist using callback ref like you're currently having, then you can pass the id prop: (Also, I think the answer you're looking for is)

```
renderInput(id) {
    <TextInput
        ref={(input) => this.myInput = input}
        id={id} {/* you were missing this in fact */}
    />
}
```

Now, to get that id:

```
this.myInput.id // will work fine, coz we have id prop now
// gets DOM id that you assigned in your element
```

Comment: Did he even assigned his ref properly in the component ? `this.myInput = React.createRef();` Without that he won't be able to access it.

Comment: @KurtMiller was updating while you commented.

Comment: Ok. I think this is very basic. OP doesn't seem to have research a lot..... For instance [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) would help him a  lot

Comment: answer updated. OP was missing id prop as far as I understand the issue.